# I have an issue reading data from my fireStore to display using Stream

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat service in my flutter application for that, I have a chat room collection in my fireStore named "chat_rooms" and I am trying to extract data from the collection.
After I run the code, nothing shows on the screen. I don't even get an error message.

1. This is the code for the stream builder:

```
//build  message list
 Widget _buildMessageList() {
   return StreamBuilder(
     stream: _chatService.getMessages(
       widget.receiverUserID,
       _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid,
     ),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return Text('Error ${snapshot.error.toString()}');
       }
       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
         return const Text('Loading');
       }
       return ListView(
         children: snapshot.data!.docs
             .map((document) => _buildMessageItem(document))
             .toList(),
       );
     },
   );
 }

//build a message item
 Widget _buildMessageItem(DocumentSnapshot document) {
   Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

   //align the messages to the right if the sender is the current user, otherwise to the left
   var alignment = (data['senderId'] == _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
       ? Alignment.centerRight
       : Alignment.centerLeft;
   return Container(
     alignment: alignment,
     child: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
       child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment:
             (data['senderId'] == _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
                 ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                 : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
         mainAxisAlignment:
             (data['senderId'] == _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
                 ? MainAxisAlignment.end
                 : MainAxisAlignment.start,
         children: [
           Text(data['senderEmail']),
           const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
           ChatBubble(message: data['message']),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

//buiild a message Input
 Widget _buildMessageInput() {
   return Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
     child: Row(
       children: [
         //text field
         Expanded(
           child: MyTextField(
             controller: _messageController,
             hintText: 'Ecrivez votre message ici',
             obscureText: false,
           ),
         ),

         //send button
         IconButton(
           onPressed: sendMessage,
           icon: const Icon(
             Icons.arrow_upward,
             size: 40,
           ),
         )
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

2. And this is the code for Services:

```
import 'package:bellehouse/model/messages_class.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatService extends ChangeNotifier {
//get the instance of auth and firestore
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final FirebaseFirestore _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

//SEND MESSAGES
Future<void> sendMessage(String receiverId, String message) async {
  //get the current user info
  final String currentUserId = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;

  final String currentUserEmail = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.email.toString();
  final Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.now();

  //create a new message
  AMessage newMessage = AMessage(
    senderId: currentUserId,
    senderEmail: currentUserEmail,
    receiverId: receiverId,
    timestamp: timestamp,
    message: message,
  );
  //construct chat room id from current user id and receiver id (sorted to ensure uniqueness)
  List<String> ids = [receiverId, currentUserId];
  ids.sort(); //sort the ids (this ensures the chat room id is always the same for any pair of users)
  String chatRoomId = ids.join("_");
  //add new message to the database
  await _fireStore
      .collection('chat_rooms')
      .doc(chatRoomId)
      .collection('messages')
      .add(newMessage.toMap());
}

//GET MESSAGES
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getMessages(String userId, String otherUserId) {
  //construct chat room id from user ids (sorted to ensure it matches the id used when sending mesages)
  List<String> ids = [userId, otherUserId];
  ids.sort();
  String chatRoomId = ids.join("_");
  return _fireStore
      .collection('chat_rooms')
      .doc(chatRoomId)
      .collection('messages')
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: false)
      .snapshots();
}
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. I recommend that you debug the code you shared locally, and edit your question to include the result of that. So if you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The issue arrives when I retrieve the data from firestore specifically at the line where I pass the stream. Because I have tried to chance the stream with other value and the code runes perfectly.